# Ionic + AngularFire2 Service - On Native App Firebase Functions Fail, On Desktop they Work

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm using Ionic to build an app. I'm using Firebase, and thus using AngularFire2, to manage database functionality. I put all my database functions into a service.

In the Angular components I have the database bindings, and when a user say, adds a new items, I simply pass they `$key` to my service (which also has a database reference / binding) and it runs the query, such as update or remove or whatever.

*Example*:

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class MovieListService {

lists: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.lists = db.list(id + '/mainLists/'); 
    }

    addNewList(title: string) {
        this.lists.push(new List(title));
    } 

}
```

Then I have my normal components:

**lists.ts**

```
...
lists: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.lists = this.db.list('/' + id + '/mainLists/');
}

onNewList() {
    this.service.addNewList('My List');
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
}
...
```

This is a rough example of how the data flow happens. I re-use some functions, so I really wanted to compartmentalize all of the Firebase stuff into a service. IS that a bad practice? Like I said, it works great on `ionic serve` in the desktop web browser, but when I `ionic cordova run android` run the app on the phone, I go to click to add a new list and the app does nothing. There's not really a way for me to see feedback since I don't have a console. The app doesn't freeze, I can go to other views and such, but the button to add is lifeless, so I know it must be the AngularFire2 commands that aren't working natively.

***EDIT 1***

I added `this.navCtrl.popToRoot();` to the code above, because this is how I have my app set. I've set `toast`s and I know that it's entering the service, but the page is *not* popping back to root. I've also added a promise to the angularfire2 method:

```
const promise = this.lists.push(new List(title));
promise
    .then( res => {
        let toast1 = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: JSON.stringify('THEN'),
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'bottom'
        });
        toast1.present();
    })
    .catch( err => {
        let toast2 = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: JSON.stringify('CATCH'),
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'bottom'
        });
        toast2.present();
    });
```

I do not get either of these toasts, therefore the line `this.movieLists.push(new MovieList(title));` **DOES NOT** execute on my native device.

Any ideas why it's not executing? Is it made for web browser and not meant to be used in a native app or something? This makes zero sense, theoretically, it should be working, and in the web browser, it is.

***EDIT 2 (Update)***

So here's the behavior:

1. Install the app
2. Run it for the first time. Data that already exists in Firebase displays immediately. But when I try to add new data or submit changes that involve Firebase commands, it doesn't work.
3. Exit the app, remove from memory. (App still installed, just re-starting).
4. Run app for second time.
5. App runs perfectly.

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I incorporate part of the user data into the database, so I have my list retrievals inside of a `.subscribe` for the user:

*service.ts*

```
constructor(private http: Http,
            private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
            private authService: AuthService) {

    this.authService.user.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
        this.user = user;

        this.lists = db.list(user.uid + '/lists/');

        var data = {};
        data['/user'] = {
            displayName: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
            photoUrl: user.photoURL,
            uid: user.uid
        };
        db.object(user.uid).update(data);
    });
}
```

I think it's the user subscription throughout my app that's causing problems. Here's another:

1. Enter the app and sign in. I'm redirected to the main page, favorite, which is one of two tabs.
2. Enter the 2nd tab (successfully), which is *list* tab. Go back to *favorite* tab.
3. Now *list* tab is locked, I can't click it. The app is not frozen, but the clicking on that tab does not work.

Example from *app.component.ts*:

```
this.authService.user.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
    if (user) {
        this.userProfile = user;
        this.onLoad(TabsPage);
    } else {
        this.userProfile = null;
        this.onLoad(SigninPage);
    }
});
```

*auth.ts*

```
user: Observable<firebase.User>;

constructor(private facebook: Facebook,
            private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
            private platform: Platform,
            private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    this.user = afAuth.authState;

}

signinGoogle(): void {}
signinFacebook(): void {}
signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}
```

Comment: Can you run it on the sdk emulator?

Comment: The weirdest thing is happening. Yes, I just tested on the sdk emulator. The same thing. BUT, I unplugged my physical phone from the computer and restarted the application. Immediately, I had full functionality. So it seems to be that when the phone is connected to the computer (or emulator running, also connected to some kind of maybe debugging state??) that it won't execute the angularfire functions. But when the device isn't tethered, then it works properly.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you deployed it to the emulator, it didn't work. Then you disconnected the phone and it worked on the emulator?

Comment: Two separate scenarios. I ran on emulator, the same occurred: the angularfire functions weren't executing. I ran `ionic cordova run android` with phone tethered, the app runs, the functions don't execute (not working). I then disconnect the phone, close the app, re-open app, it works.